# Why does sphinx autodoc output a decorator's docstring when there are two decorators in a method?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, python-decorators, autodoc

Using sphinx autodoc I want to generate documentation for the method that has `@classproperty` and `@classmethod` decorators. Instead of the method's documentation I get `@classmethod`'s documentation. If I delete any of the decorators everything works properly.
Class code is structured like below:

```
class Example(object):
    @classproperty
    @classmethod
    def example_method(cls):
       """Method description"""
       pass
```

Classproperty decorator:

```
class classproperty(property):
    def __get__(self, obj, type=None):
        return self.fget.__get__(None, type)()
```

And I am generating the documentation using:

```
.. autoclass:: Example
    :members:
```

Comment: What is `classproperty`? How can we reproduce this?

Comment: I've updated the question with classproperty code so you can reproduce it now

Answer (score 2):

From the [Sphinx documentation](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#directive-autoattribute),

> Note
>
> If you document decorated functions or methods, keep in mind that autodoc retrieves its docstrings by importing the module and inspecting the **doc** attribute of the given function or method. That means that if a decorator replaces the decorated function with another, it must copy the original **doc** to the new function.
>
> From Python 2.5, functools.wraps() can be used to create well-behaved decorating functions.

So I think the problem here is that your decorator is dropping the docstring when it wraps the function. `wraps` should be able to help with this.

You could follow the pattern from the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functools.html) on the subject. For your use case, you might do:

```
from functools import wraps

def classpropertymethod(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return classproperty(classmethod(f(*args, **kwargs)))
    return wrapper

@classpropertymethod
def example_method(cls):
    """Method description"""
    pass
```

This should get the docstring from `example_method` passed through correctly.

Comment: I came across this issue today. This procedure using `wraps` solves the issue. +1